# RPC call cannot find method

Tags: go, rpc, distributed-system, consensus, raft

I'm trying to implement Raft consensus algorithm but for some reason having trouble using RPC calls. I'm using labrpc.go to make calls.

My function signature:

```
func (rf *Raft) RequestVotes(args RequestVoteArgs, reply *RequestVoteReply) bool
```

and the call I'm making

```
if err := rf.peers[peerIdx].Call("Raft.RequestVotes", args, &reply); err == false {
```

Raft struct:

```
type Raft struct {
... 
peers     []*labrpc.ClientEnd // RPC end points of all peers
...
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> labrpc.Service.dispatch(): unknown method RequestVotes in Raft.RequestVotes; expecting one of []

I also have several other `Raft.` methods, so should the *expecting one of []* be non-empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RPC methods weren't being recognized as RPC methods as I was explicitly returning `bool`. Changing the code to return void (removing the return entirely) fixed the issue.

Updated function signature:

```
func (rf *Raft) RequestVotes(args RequestVoteArgs, reply *RequestVoteReply) {
```